# Why my manifest.json file could not be fetched or parsed?

Tags: json, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I've made PWA I hosted locally, and it was working fine. Once I uploaded everything to a hosting service it seems to just not work anymore. I checked Lighthouse and it mentioned that there is something wrong with the manifest file.

[Heres the message Lighthouse gave me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8EpW.png)

I'm confused on why there is a problem with the manifest file since it worked fine on the local host.

Heres the manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name":"Punto Tuzo",
    "short_name":"PuntoTuzo",
    "start_url":"https://puntotuzo.epizy.com",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "icons/manifest-icon-192.maskable.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
          },
          {
            "src": "icons/manifest-icon-192.maskable.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
          },
          {
            "src": "icons/manifest-icon-512.maskable.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
          },
          {
            "src": "icons/manifest-icon-512.maskable.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
          }
    ],
    "theme_color":"#000000",
    "background_color":"#FFFFFF",
    "display":"fullscreen",
    "orientation":"portrait"
}
```

Is there way I can fixt this issue? Thank you for your help and time.

Originally, I thought it had something to do with the "start url" since in the local host version it had the following:

```
"start_url":"/?home=true"
```

So, I changed it to the sites URL:

```
"start_url":"https://puntotuzo.epizy.com"
```

But it looks like that wasn't it since nothing really changed.

Comment: The error message reads like the manifest file itself is not being served at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. You are not introducing a service worker which will handle the offline version of the page.
Please read this page VERY carefully: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/?utm_source=xron.net

Especially the parts about `prefer_related_applications` and `related_applications` and the `Special considerations for when using content security policy` at the bottom of the page, about CSP.